# How to work History.back() in IE8 and above Versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, dotnetnuke

I'm facing a big issue related to "Back Button",
Currently I am using JavaScript back button  like - parent.history.back();
but it is giving error like "Webpage has expired" on clicking Back button. is there any solution to get rid of it. My Project is in Asp.net.Every comment is appreciated.
Thank you..!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working example (tested on saucelabs IE7, IE8, IE9 @Windows XP and Vista)

```
<input type="button" id="push-me" value="Push me!" onclick="window.history.back(); return false;"/>
```

If it still doesn't work for you may ensure that your tests are not executed within an `iframe` but a separate window.

Comment: Whoops didn't see the last sentence with ASP.net... :/
I hope `window.history.back();` works for you.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me! Important: it is mandatory to `return false;` when you are using the `<button>` element not `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a syntax error.

```
onclick="history.go(); return false;"
```

or

```
onclick="history.go(-1); return false;"
```

should work. Else you could try document referrer instead:

```
location.href = document.referrer;
```

Comment: Its working on all browser without IE8 and IE9..is there any extra script to add on page.