# Page has expired after postback event in IE11

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a problem when i click a hyperlink to pop up a report; the main page will display 'The Page Has Expired'. It happens when i click a `RadioButtonList` and then click a button. The `RadioButtonList` has a `postback` function and the button will pop up a new window using `javascript`. Meanwhile, if i didn't click the `RadioButtonList` and only click the button and then click the hyperlink; it will not produce 'The Page Has Expired'.  May i know what is the problem behind this and how i can solve this?

the `javascript` function when the button clicked:

```
function buttonClicked(event, object) {
    var variableA = "<%=variableA %>";
    var variableB = "<%=variableB %>";
    var variableC = "<%=variableC %>";
    window.open('../Common/RandomPage.aspx?variableA=' + variableA + '&variableB=' + variableB + '&variableC=' + variableC, '', ' height=500,width=850,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes');
}
```

the `RadioButtonList` in aspx:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
```

the `RadioButtonList` function when RadioButton clicked(.cs):

```
protected void RadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //hide/show some details;
}
```

Comment: Are you going to show us some code?

Comment: @MickSharpe i've updated my post. But it is just basic thing and that is why it confuses me

Comment: Please post the code of your main aspx page which contains the radiobuttonlist.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh i've put it in the post. Thank you

Comment: Check if this is solving your problem ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376909/how-to-avoid-web-page-has-expired-in-ie

Comment: @Baskar that is one of the solutions that i look into. But still it is still the same. I notice the page only display 'webpage has expired' only when it is on postback before i click the hyperlink

Comment: Are you using any Update Panel in your application ?

Comment: @Baskar yes. will that affect this?

Comment: May be the steps here resolves your issue.http://forums.asp.net/t/1760340.aspx?Radiobutton+list+causing+Full+POstback+in+Update+Panel

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. There's `History.back()` method in the code which basically function as clicking the ‘Back Button’ in the browser. Here is i solve my problem:

[How to work History.back() in IE8 and above Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561152/how-to-work-history-back-in-ie8-and-above-versions)